# Alarm which is fired on specific time each day

Tags: java, android, calendar, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an alarm that let's say fire on 15:00 O'Clock.

I want it to fire every day on 15:00.

 so I wrote this code:

```
     sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, ID, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
     alarm.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
     alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
     long alarmCal=alarm.getTimeInMillis();
     if (alarmCal<=new Date().getTime()) {
        alarm.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
     }
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

Will it really fire everyday on 15:00?

Thank you!

Comment: I think (but don't recall for sure) that you'll need to handle the case where your alarm gets set and then the device gets turned off. I am not certain that your alarm will still fire after the reboot. You also need to consider what should happen if the device is off at the time the alarm would fire. As for whether it will fire every day. You can test on your device by going in to settings and setting the date forward by one, and setting the time to 14:59. You can do that as many times as you like to test thoroughly.

Comment: I have already handled it. I have a broadcastReciever that activates the alarm when the device is turned on, so it's okay...
I'm just not sure if there is a chance that my code will set the time to the past...

Comment: Looks fine the way to check it is change the time on your emulator clock! Also I wrote a Tut on this http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/ :-D

Comment: Well, but it doesn't work... Iv'e got a notification today on 7:49... not the required time... What can cause it?